# How to find list values amongst keys in list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a list that looks like this:

```
ids = [123, 127]
```

And I want to match these ids to the "id" values in a list of dictionaries.  Then, I want to write specific fields of these dictionaries to a new list of dictionaries.  Here is the original list of dictionaries:

```
oldDicts = [
    {
        "id": 120,
        "name": "Syrup",
        "units": 105,
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Honey",
        "units": 175,
    },
    {
        "id": 127,
        "name": "Wax",
        "units": 179,
    },
    {
        "id": 207,
        "name": "Grease",
        "units": 648,
    }
]
```

The desired list of new dictionaries would look like this:

```
newDicts = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Honey",
    },
    {
        "id": 127,
        "name": "Wax",
    }
]
```

I know that I can iterate over the values in the list and pull out the specific values the using the dictionary get method, and then append the values as dictionaries to the list using the append method:

```
itemID = int()
itemName = ""
newDicts = []

for item in oldDicts:
    itemID = item.get("id")
    itemName = item.get("name")
    interimDict = {itemID:itemName} 
    newDicts.append(interimDict)
```

However, I am stuck regarding how to add a step before this to apply this logic to only the dictionaries where oldDicts "id" key equals a value from the ids list (["123", "127"]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an if statement to check for the IDs in the list.

```
ids = [123, 127]

itemID = int()
itemName = ""
newDicts = []

for item in oldDicts:
    itemID = item.get("id")
    itemName = item.get("name")
    if itemID in ids:
        interimDict = {itemID:itemName}
        newDicts.append(interimDict)

print(newDicts)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems so easy now that I'm looking at it!  I didn't think to put the if statement after the getting the itemID.  I was trying to figure out the syntax to do something like  "for item in ids, if oldDicts["id"] in ids" but that seems like I was overthinking it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's always useful to have someone else look at the problem from a different angle :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible one-line solution:

```
newDicts = [{'id': dct['id'], 'name': dct['name']}
            for dct in oldDicts if dct['id'] in ids]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
itemID = int()
itemName = ""
newDicts = []

for item in oldDicts:
    if item in [123, 127, 128]:
        itemID = item.get("id")
        itemName = item.get("name")
        interimDict = {itemID:itemName} 
        newDicts.append(interimDict)
```

Try that, it only appends if the item is one of the three

Comment: Don't hard code ids list. Like `if item in ids`.